# Search engine with two inputfields coming up with the same result

Tags: php, jquery, function, html-table

I have been trying to make a search engine where I have two inputfields, both are searching in the same database and table but different rows/columns. My problem is they both search in both rows/columns. I'm adding screenshots at the bottom so you can understand me better.

I'm suspecting there's something wrong the functions in document 2, but I can't understand what.

Here's the code in two documents.

**Document 1**

```
mysql_connect ("localhost","xxxx","xxxx") or die ("Tilkoblingsfeil");
mysql_select_db ("xxxx") or die("Finner ikke database");
$output = '';

if(isset($_POST['searchVal']))  {
    $searchq = $_POST['searchVal'];
    $searchq = preg_replace ("#^0-9#"," ",$searchq);

    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ds_OrderItem WHERE idProduct LIKE '%$searchq%' LIMIT 100") or die("Klarte ikke søke!");
    $count = mysql_num_rows ($query);

    if($count == 0){
        $output = 'Ingen produktID med disse verdiene';




}else{


    $output .='<table border="1" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="1" width="50%" bordercolor="grey"><tr><th>ProduktID</th><th>Ordrenummer</th><th>Beskrivelse</th><th>Antall</th>';
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    $output .= '<tr><td>'.$row['idProduct'].'</td><td>'.$row['idOrder'].'</td><td>'.$row['title'].'</td><td>'.$row['qty'].'</td></tr>';
}   
        $output .='</table>';




      if($_POST['searchVal'] == NULL) {
            $output = "";
            }

    }

}
if(isset($_POST['searchVal']))  {
    $searchw = $_POST['searchVal'];
    $searchw = preg_replace ("#^0-9a-z#i"," ",$searchw);

    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ds_OrderItem WHERE title LIKE '%$searchw%' LIMIT 100") or die("Klarte ikke søke!");
    $count = mysql_num_rows ($query);

    if($count == 0){
        $output = 'Ingen TECDOC artikler med disse verdiene';




    }else{


        $output .='<table border="1" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="1" width="50%" bordercolor="grey"><tr><th>ProduktID</th><th>Ordrenummer</th><th>Beskrivelse</th><th>Antall</th>';
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
        $output .= '<tr><td>'.$row['idProduct'].'</td><td>'.$row['idOrder'].'</td><td>'.$row['title'].'</td><td>'.$row['qty'].'</td></tr>';
}   
        $output .='</table>';




      if($_POST['searchVal'] == NULL) {
                $output = "";
            }

    }

}
echo ($output);

?>
```

**Document 2**

```
<?php
error_reporting(1);
include('system_admin.inc.php');

make_header($title,array('enable_ajax' => true));


?>

<html>


<head>
<title>TecdocORProduct</title>
<script type=text/javascript " src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type=text/javascript ">



function searchq() {
    var searchTxt = $("input[name='search1']").val();

    $.post("testsearch.php", {searchVal: searchTxt}, function(output) {
        $("#output") .html(output);



    });


}   
function searchw() {
    var searchTxt = $("input[name='search2']").val();

    $.post("testsearch.php", {searchVal: searchTxt}, function(output) {
        $("#output") .html(output);     




});

}
</script>

</head>


<body>
<h1>Søk i produktID eller tecdocnr</h1>


<form class="odd" action="william.properties.php" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="search1" placeholder="Søk etter produktID" onkeyup="searchq();" />



<form class="odd" action="william.properties.php" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="search2" placeholder="Søk etter tecdocnr" onkeyup="searchw();" />


        <div id="output">


</div>

</form>





</body>
</html>
```

Thank you for your time and any answers I might be given.

[image: The right searchfield]

[image: The left searchfield]

Comment: You should use unique keys for your both search request's `{searchVal: searchTxt}` or `{searchVal2: searchTxt}`

Comment: So for my searhw function im replacing searchVal with searchVal2?

Comment: differentiate the data like this { idproduct : searchTxt}  { title:searchtxt }

Comment: @easyquestions added answer change your js and php code like that, let me know

Comment: Please read up on using PDO and prepared statements. Your code is exposed to SQL injection attacks and should not be used in any kind of production evironment! Here's a start: https://phpdelusions.net/pdo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use unique keys for your both search request's `{searchVal: searchTxt}` or `{searchVal2: searchTxt}` and use in php search conditions accordingly

Try changing your `js` and `php` code like below:

**JS:**

```
function searchq() {
    var searchTxt = $("input[name='search1']").val();

    $.post("testsearch.php", {searchVal: searchTxt}, function(output) {
        $("#output") .html(output);



    });


}   
function searchw() {
    var searchTxt = $("input[name='search2']").val();

    $.post("testsearch.php", {searchVal2: searchTxt}, function(output) {
        $("#output") .html(output);     




});

}
```

**Php:**

```
mysql_connect ("localhost","xxxx","xxxx") or die ("Tilkoblingsfeil");
mysql_select_db ("xxxx") or die("Finner ikke database");
$output = '';

if(isset($_POST['searchVal']))  {
    $searchq = $_POST['searchVal'];
    $searchq = preg_replace ("#^0-9#"," ",$searchq);

    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ds_OrderItem WHERE idProduct LIKE '%$searchq%' LIMIT 100") or die("Klarte ikke søke!");
    $count = mysql_num_rows ($query);

    if($count == 0){
        $output = 'Ingen produktID med disse verdiene';




}else{


    $output .='<table border="1" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="1" width="50%" bordercolor="grey"><tr><th>ProduktID</th><th>Ordrenummer</th><th>Beskrivelse</th><th>Antall</th>';
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    $output .= '<tr><td>'.$row['idProduct'].'</td><td>'.$row['idOrder'].'</td><td>'.$row['title'].'</td><td>'.$row['qty'].'</td></tr>';
}   
        $output .='</table>';




      if($_POST['searchVal'] == NULL) {
            $output = "";
            }

    }
exit($output);
}
if(isset($_POST['searchVal2']))  {
    $searchw = $_POST['searchVal2'];
    $searchw = preg_replace ("#^0-9a-z#i"," ",$searchw);

    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ds_OrderItem WHERE title LIKE '%$searchw%' LIMIT 100") or die("Klarte ikke søke!");
    $count = mysql_num_rows ($query);

    if($count == 0){
        $output = 'Ingen TECDOC artikler med disse verdiene';




    }else{


        $output .='<table border="1" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="1" width="50%" bordercolor="grey"><tr><th>ProduktID</th><th>Ordrenummer</th><th>Beskrivelse</th><th>Antall</th>';
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
        $output .= '<tr><td>'.$row['idProduct'].'</td><td>'.$row['idOrder'].'</td><td>'.$row['title'].'</td><td>'.$row['qty'].'</td></tr>';
}   
        $output .='</table>';




      if($_POST['searchVal'] == NULL) {
                $output = "";
            }

    }
exit($output);
}


?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to differentiate the post data name `{ idproduct : searchTxt} and  { title:searchtxt }`

**JS :**

```
        function searchq() {
        var searchTxt = $("input[name='search1']").val();

        $.post("testsearch.php", {idproduct: searchTxt}, function(output) {
            $("#output") .html(output);



        });


    }   
    function searchw() {
        var searchTxt = $("input[name='search2']").val();

        $.post("testsearch.php", {title: searchTxt}, function(output) {
            $("#output") .html(output);     

    });

    }
```

**PHP :**

```
if(isset($_POST['idproduct']))  { ....  }

if(isset($_POST['title']))  { ....  }
```

Comment: glad to help you @easyquestions